# “.Private/” directory taking up tons of disk space and no indication of what what might cause it

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ubuntu-16.04

Today I came in and it seems that my `.Private/` directory is taking up a lot of disk space (.ecryptfs dir). I have a total of `10.9T` of storage on my system. I am running an Ubuntu 16.04 server and  have the server admins home folder encrypted. When I attempt to make a file I get the following:

```
touch test1.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test1.txt': No space left on device
```

When I do a scan of the file system I receive this:

```
df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            1.6G  157M  1.4G  11% /run
/dev/mapper/TBG--Magic--vg-root  2.7T  2.7T     0 100% /
tmpfs                            7.7G   12K  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda2                        473M   96M  353M  22% /boot
/dev/sda1                        511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
/home/serveradmin/.Private       2.7T  2.7T     0 100% /home/serveradmin
tmpfs                            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb2                        7.3T  133G  7.2T   2% /mnt
```

However, when I do a full scan on everything, I get something completely different:

```
sudo du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G|T"
14M /etc
2.4G    /usr
213M    /root
4.6M    /libx32
14M /sbin
14G /home
2.2G    /var
10G /Users
1.2T    /srv
555M    /lib
97M /boot
132G    /mnt
157M    /run
1.4G    /nsm
du: cannot access '/proc/197133/task/197133/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/197133/task/197133/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/197133/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/197133/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
16M /bin
3.9M    /lib32
1.3T    /
1.3T    total
```

This is causing a lot of writing file issues. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. It seems that when I mounted my backup system I didn't do it properly and all my backups had been being saved to my local drive. A simple unmount remove and remount did the trick: `sudo umount /dev/sdb2 && sudo rm /mnt/* && sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt`